# Why does InitializeTouchInjection cause warnings in event viewer?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, touch

I get warnings in the event viewer when calling InitializeTouchInjection:

> A pointer device did not report a valid unit of angular measurement.
>
> A pointer device reported a bad angular physical range.
>
> A pointer device reported a bad angular logical range.

Is there a way to fix this?